# Scala PartialFunctions from concrete ones

Tags: scala, partialfunction

Is there any quick way to use as a concrete function (of type, say, `(A) => B`) as a `PartialFunction[A, B]`?  The most concise syntax I know of is:

```
(a: A) => a match { case obj => func(obj) }
```

Is there an implicit conversion anywhere, something like:

```
implicit def funcAsPartial[A, B](func: A => B) = new PartialFunction[A, B] {

  def isDefinedAt(a: A) = true
  def apply(a: A) = func(a)

}
```

I guess I just wrote what I was looking for, but does this already exist in the Scala libraries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing this with an implicit conversion is dangerous, for the same reason that `(A) => B` should not inherit from `PartialFunction[A, B]`.  That is, the contract of PartialFunction guarantees that you can safely* call `apply` wherever `isDefinedAt` returns `true`.  Function1's contract provides no such guarantee.

Your implicit conversion will result in a PartialFunction that violates its contract if you apply it to a function that is not defined everywhere. Instead, use a pimp to make the conversion explicit:

```
implicit def funcAsPartial[A, B](f: A => B) = new {
   /** only use if `f` is defined everywhere */
   def asPartial(): PartialFunction[A, B] = {
      case a => f(a)
   }

   def asPartial(isDefinedAt: A => Boolean): PartialFunction[A, B] = {
      case a if isDefinedAt(a) => f(a)
   }
}

// now you can write
val f = (i: Int) => i * i

val p = f.asPartial // defined on all integers
val p2 = f.asPartial(_ > 0) // defined only on positive integers
```

* As discussed in the comments, it may not be entirely clear what "safety" means here. The way I think about it is that a PartialFunction explicitly declares its domain in the following precise sense: if `isDefinedAt` returns true for a value `x`, then `apply(x)` can be evaluated in a way that is consistent with the intent of the function's author. That *does not* imply that `apply(x)` will not throw an exception, but merely that the exception was part of the design of the function (and should be documented).

Comment: Thank you; I had the misconception that Function1 implied being defined over the entire domain.

Comment: @AaronNovstrup: your explanation of PartialFunction's contract is the only one which makes sense, but is not reflected by ScalaDocs (at least until 2.9.1). `PartialFunction`'s ScalaDocs claim that: "A partial function of type `PartialFunction[A, B]` is a unary function where the domain does not necessarily include all values of type `A`." Moreover, they never claim that it is safe (in what sense) to call f wherever defined, and that's rather easy to violate, as done by the `PartialFunction` literal `{ case 0 => 1 / 0 }`.
Where did you get that info? Does a bug report need to be filed?

Comment: @Blaisorblade I believe that I read this explanation on the mailing list when I was learning Scala (it's been a while), and I wasn't looking at any documentation when I wrote this answer. And, yes, it is easy and even somewhat common to violate this contract (e.g., to wrap/rethrow an exception in a catch block).  The real point is that PartialFunctions define their domain while ordinary Functions do not (with some fuzziness about what that actually means).

Comment: @Blaisorblade The documentation should probably be revised along the lines of the changes I just added to my answer.

Comment: While searching among existing bug reports, I found this explanation from Odersky - which matches what you read: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.internals/2057.
I created a bugreport for docs as discussed, linking back here and citing your name and suggestions:
https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5370

Answer (score 0):

No, I tried to find one a few months ago and ended up writing my own that's essentially the same as yours.

Comment: It seems to me that `(A) => B` should inherit from `PartialFunction[A, B]`, not the other way around.

Comment: I would agree with that, on the ground that a (total) Function is a Partial function which happens to be defined everywhere (isDefinedAt(x) = true). Martin Odersky however says a Function is not guaranteed to be a total Function, it is just that its domain is undocumented. So a PartialFunction is a Function which documents its domain.